# Unlink using execCommand without a selection

Tags: javascript, execcommand

I was wondering if it is possible to use  `document.execCommand("unlink", false, false)` without a selection before.
Or in other words, is it possible to simulate a selection so we can use `execCommand` as I'm expecting to do ?

**EDIT :**
To be more precise, I would like to use `range` object to simulate a selection. [In this example](http://jsfiddle.net/6nbpfq0d/) you can see that I'm checking if the caret is in a `<a>` tag. So from here, I would like to unlink without selecting the whole text.

Comment: ...what are you trying to do? And in what? (browser? Nodejs?)

Comment: I'm trying to unlink a part of an editable document using `execCommand`. But to make `execCommand` work, there must be a selection before. Thus, I want to avoid this step of selection each time. So to simplify all this, I'm using `document.getSelection().anchorNode` to know if the caret is in a `<a>` tag and now I would like to unlink from here without selecting the whole link.

Comment: Can you show what you're doing in a codepen or jsbin? Because using `document.getSelection()` when a contenteditable element is being editing will give you a `#text` element, not an HTML element, so that won't help you all that much in unlinking.

Comment: I think that we're getting a bit far from my question. Btw, [here's an exemple.](http://jsfiddle.net/6nbpfq0d/) I'm not really having issue with `getSelection()` and _unlinking_ is just an example. My question was more general. I just want to give to  `execCommand` a "matter" to work with when there's no selection _(in so far as this function needs a selection to deal with)_. I didn't want to orient this topic but in my opinion, we can do it with `range` object. If it's the case, how is it possible to do that ?

Comment: at this point I'd strongly urge you to edit your post and work in all the information from your comments so far. If you need to build a selection, then a `range` is definitely the way to achieve that.